# How Java treat method reference of instance methods?

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I'm reading [Oracle's Java SE tutorial on method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and I came across the problem of method reference's mechanism of parsing instance methods.

In the tutorial, there's a snippet using method reference as a `Comparator<String>` argument.

```java
Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

I think that a `Comparator<String>` object should implement `compare(String, String)` rather than an instance method taking one explicit parameter. How does Java's compiler treat this, or what happened at compile time?

After learning about the JVM I understand the implicit parameter is passed as an argument. But this didn't help me understand how the Java compiler treat this method reference.

Could someone help me with finding a tutorial or documentation on this? Which part do I need more understanding on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String::compareToIgnoreCase` conforms to `Comparator<String>` because it does accept two String arguments and returns an int. The first argument is the instance of String upon which to invoke the instance method. The second argument is the (single) parameter to be passed to that instance method.

It's the same as this

```
(a, b) -> a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)
```

or more verbosely

```
(String a, String b) -> { 
    return a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
}
```

So yes, `compareToIgnoreCase` only takes one argument, but `String::compareToIgnoreCase` takes two.

Contrast that with `"foo"::compareToIgnoreCase` (or say, `someSpecificStr::compareToIgnoreCase`). Here, the instance is already bound, so it only takes one argument.

Comment: Actually, it returns `int`, not boolean.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much. Your last example helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`String::compareToIgnoreCase` is a lambda interpretation of

```
new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
    }
};
```

in `String::compareToIgnoreCase` the `String` is `o1`

`compareToIgnoreCase` await a string as an input parameter, and that is `o2`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is it the compiler's functionality of interpreting an instance method into the form you wrote? Do you know where can I read more about this?

Comment: Yes, you can read more [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html)